# Bluetooth in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: bluetooth

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a new laptop just a few moments ago.

I installed it via DVD RW on which I have copied an iso image downloaded from official Ubuntu site. With this DVD I have already installed Ubuntu 13.10 on another laptop ( about a month ago ) on which no errors have occurred ( so far ).

However on this laptop I seem to have a problem with bluetooth. Every time I try to turn it off in settings menu, it turns itself back on. It's quite annoying...

Computer software is up-to-date ( no update fixed this )..,

Anyone has a clue with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround for the opposite situation (turn bluetooth on and it turns iself back off), may it'll work for you... Open a terminal and type "rfkill list all":

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

If you see the same output ("Soft blocked: yes"), just type "sudo rfkill unblock all":

```
$ sudo rfkill unblock all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Worked for me, bluetooth's indicator appears in the panel again and bluetooth is activated.

You could use "rfkill" for enabling and disabling the wireless devices. You can list all the wireless devices with indexes using the "rfkill list" command. For example:

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
1: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
2: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
```

In this case, there are four devices with indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3. The rfkill block and unblock commands are "rfkill block index|type" and "rfkill unblock index|type". The block command disables the indicated device whereas the unblock command enables it. A device is identified by the device index or the device type. The device type is one of the following: all, wifi, wlan, bluetooth, uwb, ultrawideband, wimax, wwan, gps or fm.

Following with the example, by typing:

```
rfkill block 0
```

Someone could turn off the bluetooth device recognized as "hci0: Bluetooth" with index "0".